# array indexOf returns -1

Tags: jquery, arrays

Just starting to learn jquery and making my own lightbox as a project. I have made a varable that returns an array of all the imgs with a data tag in the anchor. Now I am making it so when you click on an image it reurns its index in the array so I can switch through the images (not sure how to do that yet) but the index returns -1?? When I console out the array it lists both images.

```
var ocularTags = $('body').find("[data-ocular]");
var ocularArray = $.makeArray(ocularTags);

//click binded to image
$('a[data-ocular]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    console.log( ocularArray.indexOf($this)); 

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `indexOf` on objects which wont work. It will always return `-1` because `objects` are not compared like `primitives` or `strings`.

Use jQuery [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) instead

```
console.log( ocularTags.index($this));
```

Comment: When I did this though I get "ocularArray.index is not a function"

Comment: @Packy, sorry, didnt notice you make a pure array for ocularArray. Try ocularTags.index($this) instead

Comment: Worked! So I can get the position that way then user `ocularArray` to display the total using `ocularArray.length`. To move to the next image I just add to or take away from the index.

Comment: Shoot, yes it does. Do I even need to make an array then?

Comment: @Packy, in your case I dont think so. OcularTags is a collection itself